Reduced and Unreduced Homology are esentially Equivalent
On Hatcher's Algebraic Topology section 2.3 the Axioms for (reduced) Homology (on CW-complexes) are introduced.
We have 3 axioms, first we have a functor $\tilde{h}_n(\cdot)$ from the category of CW-complexes modulo homotopy to the category of abelian groups. Second we want boundary morphisms wich fit into a natural long exact sequence. Third, we want to send wedge sum of spaces to direct sum.
Then, we define unreduced homology an relative homology changing the axioms by their relative counterparts.
Then Hatcher leaves as an excersice to check the following
"Reduced and unreduced homology theories are essetially equivalent. From an unreduced theory $h$ one gets a reduced theory $\tilde{h}$  by setting $\tilde{h}_n(X)$ equal to the kernel of the canonical map $h_n(X)\to h_n(\text{point})$. In the other direction, one set $h_n(X)\simeq \tilde{h}_n(X_+)$ where $X_+$ is the disjoint union of $X$ with a point."
I want to check these transformations are inverses of each other.
First, I would need to show the applications described are really homology theories wich I think is not so hard. But I don't know how to go about proving these transformations are inverses of each other.
A reference for this fact or a sketch of a proof would be very helpful.

Hint: Read the two sentences in Hatcher following the passage you quote. I recommend attempting a proof on your own after that and updating this question with where you get stuck; questions that show some effort fare much better on this site.
